# how to use re.sub in python to remove a character by it's unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode

for example i want to do

```
new_data = t = re.sub('[ufd3e]'),' ',new_data)
```

to replace the character uf3ef but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: Python accepts utf-8 by default. You likely can just put `'[﴾]'` in your code.

Comment: `\ufd3e` works, but no need for square brackets, which means "choose one of", when you only have one character.  For that matter, no need for a regular expression at all.  Just use `new_data = new_data.replace('\ufd3e',' ')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `\u` to tell it it is unicode  (and you had a closing parenthesis in the wrong place)

```
new_data = t = re.sub(u'[\ufd3e]',' ',new_data)
```